# Tkinter fullscreen extra window

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter

I am running a program where I am creating a additional Tk window in fullscreen and I get an annoying extra window.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, Frame
import tkinter.font as TkFont

def startup():
    root.destroy()
    program = tk.Toplevel()
    program.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

I have not tried very much but I couldn´t find a solution by simply browsing.

Comment: If you have destroyed the main/root window, then use `Tk()` instead of `Toplevel()`.

Comment: *"I have not tried very much but I couldn´t find a solution by simply browsing."* Please do some research **before** posting on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The extra window is the `Toplevel` you are creating. Instead, just set the attribute at the `root` window instead. This exeample will create a fullscreen window without the extra window you are talking about:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.mainloop()
```